# Testing iPad 4th Gen/Retina Display

Tags: css, google-chrome, ipad, media-queries, retina-display

**EDITED Aug 26th, 2015**

Ok, this question might be a bit rough because this project is still in Dev stages so legally I am not allowed to share it yet to show my problem in real time.

The problem I am having is that I am building a site for a client and when we began the testing phases I passed every test except for iPad 4th gen. We then began to discover that all my code really looks monstrously large when viewed in **ANY** retina display (4th/5th gen, iPad air).

The problem isn't that the `vh/vw` properties aren't working, the problem is that suddenly `20vh` (20% of the viewport height) is massive. I am using the padding of an inner container object to vertically center all content within its parent container by using `padding-top: 20vh; padding-bottom: 20vh;`.

I have been trying solutions here that involve targeting **ONLY** retina displays and none have worked at all. Heres what I have tried to target retina with...

- `@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width : 768px) 
  and (max-device-width : 1024px)
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) { /* STYLES GO HERE */}`
- `@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) 
  and (max-device-width : 1024px)
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
  and (min-resolution: 192dpi) { /* STYLES GO HERE */}`
- `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0">`

Problem is that doing all these techniques also targets iPad 1/2/3 as well for some reason and it is messing up my previously written code.

Comment: In Chrome when in device emulation mode, usually it wants you to refresh each time you change the device, or characteristics of the device. You probably already know this, but maybe it was worth a mention.

Comment: Thanks for the mention but I did try refreshing and no dice :(

Comment: I kind of figured that but couldn't help myself from asking. Did you try the work around provided in the answer below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`vh` units are a newer css3 unit of measure so that older browsers are going to ignore them. So normally you are going to use a fallback with vh units. Something like:

```
.container {
height: 1024px;
height: 100vh;
}
```

Browsers that don't understand vh will skip it and use pixels.

However, [Can I Use](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units) mentions that vh units are not fully supported until iOS 8. And it mentions, there is some "buggy behavior" in prior versions of Safari for iOS.  It then provides as [a work around](https://gist.github.com/pburtchaell/e702f441ba9b3f76f587) to the issue, which may be useful.

So maybe this so called buggy behavior is what you are running in to.

Comment: Yea I did mostly all of this already I should have been more specific. I wish to target only the devices with the pixel ratio of 2 but if I can't test it in chrome or ff I can't tell that it's only targeting retina displays and not the tablets stuff I already have done for normal ipads

Comment: Gave u an upvote cause I learned something new lol. Didn't know you could query by aspect ratio.

Comment: The whole thing is strange because now I am realizing that the query @media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) is targeting older iPads now too. I can't win lol. I wanna target ONLY retina to give hard coded pixel values.

Comment: also it's not that the bug is that the iPad can't see the vh or vw css props. The problem is that it sees those props just fine, however 20% of the viewport height or width is suddenly huge. Which makes no sense to me.

Comment: Yah i hear you on the first comment its tough to test on an ipad retina when you don't have both the retina and non-retina ipads. totally a pain.

Comment: On your 2nd comment, if ur using -min-device-pixel-ratio of 2 and its still hitting the older ipads that aren't retina, than those older ipads possibly are ignoring that media query b/c they don't support it. What iOS are the ipads you are referring to? Prior to iOS7.1 -min-device-pixel-ratio is not supported.Possibly there is a browser-specific hack for you: http://browserhacks.com/, or you may need to do user agent detection to deliver different css to safari for older versions of iOS .

Comment: Yea I am using an iPad 1 and 2. However when I load Chrome device mode and set it to iPad it says the pixel ratio default is already 2.

Comment: Have you tried user agent detection to target just ipad 1 and 2 with different css as a last resort?  Also your not actually testing on an iPad. Your problem is only in the developer tools device emulation mode as far as you know. browserstack.com is a decent way to test on various iPads and will be more accurate than ff or chrome developer tools.

Comment: Actually I only learned about this problem when testing with the client and on their iPad in office. It was 4th gen and that's how this all started. So I thought I need a way to test this stuff ahead of time or at all since I don't own a 4th gen.